# Node.js file rotation

Tags: node.js

I have a process that periodically gets files from a server and copy them with `SFTP` to a local directory. It should not overwrite the file if it already exists. I know with something like `Winston` I can automatically rotate the log file when it fills up, but in this case I need a similar functionality to rotate files if they already exist.

*An example:*
The routine copies a remote file called `testfile.txt` to a local directory. The next time it's run the same remote file is found and copied. But now I want to rename the first `testfile.txt` to `testfile.txt.0` so it's not overwritten. And so on - after a while I'd have a directory of files with the name `testfile.txt.N` and the most recent `testfile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can append date and time on the file name that gives every filename a unique name and also helps you archive it.

For example you `text.txt` can be either `20170202_181921_test.txt` or `test_20170202_181921.txt`

You can use a JavaScript Date Object to get date and time.

*P.S show your code of downloading files so that I can add more to that.*

Comment: While that is a solution to not overwriting the files, it's also not what I asked. I don't want to have them all named by date. As stated in the question, I want to have the most recent named the same as the remote file, and the rest of them sequentially appended with and integer - with the next most recent file having a zero and so on.

Comment: And by the way... You gave an answer to this question in a way that didn't even answer what I asked and then changed the title of the question to more accurately reflect what you thought it should be asking???

Comment: Then I think what you are trying to ask in the question is unclear. What does rotating a file means? Where did you get that word from?